add data-bs-toggle to Advanced Markers in Google Maps API
im using google maps api with react and typescript and bootstrap
i want to display a modal or any other bootstrap element when a person click a Marker/Pin on the map
this is my advanced marker element:
<AdvancedMarker
    key={location.key}
    clickable={true}
    onClick={(ev: google.maps.MapMouseEvent) => handleOpenMarker(ev, location.key)}
    position={location.coords}
>
    <Pin background={'#FBBC04'} glyphColor={'#000'} borderColor={'#000'} />
</AdvancedMarker>

it would be great if i could add data-bs-toggle="modal" and data-bs-target="#exampleModal" to this component so when someone clicks it, it displays a bootstrap modal
this is possible? how can i achieve this?
